# JBeret-UI support for multiple rest services

Tags: wildfly, jberet

I'm trying to use Scheduler with JBeret-UI to start jobs from several rest services.

I already set the restUrl in config.json to a batch rest service running in wildfly and it works ok, the jobs of that service are available in the scheduler.
But now I need to include other jobs from other rest services, and jBeret-UI doesn't support them directly.
I was trying to change the [batchRestservice.js](https://github.com/jberet/jberet-ui/blob/master/app/common/batchRestService.js) to allow receiving arrays from the [config.json](https://github.com/jberet/jberet-ui/blob/master/config.json) but there are several problems with job collection in [jobs.js](https://github.com/jberet/jberet-ui/blob/master/app/jobs/jobs.js) and job start (it adds\references the initial restUrl).

Is there some way to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That amounts to aggregate batch job data from multiple sources and display them in a single UI, which goes beyond what jberet-ui is designed for. I'd suggest you implement your own front end, while still leveraging jberet rest services.

Comment: Thanks cheng, I will try a different approach and implement a different front end